# clear a hidden input when cloning row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Im using a function to clone html table rows, with input fields, to allow the user multiple inputs.

my **html** looks like this

```
<table id="ID_1">
    <tr id="tr_id1">
        <td><input type="hidden" value="databaseid"/></td>
        <td>Inputfield 1</td>
        <td>Inputfield 2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="cloneRow('ID_1', 'tr_id1')"></button>
```

and my **javascript**

```
function cloneRow(tablename,rowname) {
    var row = document.getElementById(rowname); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById(tablename); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    $('.pickDate').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
    }); 
}
```

For further work on the next page, I need only the first `<td><input type="hidden" value="databaseid"/></td>` so by copying, it should only copy the hidden input, but without the value in side, value should look like `value=""`

How can this be solved? (jQuery can be used)

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/21sv1bug/

Comment: properly indent your code, and if possible provide fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @NitsanBaleli I just took care of the indentation... at the other hand, I see no reasons why this should be an issue testing without a fiddle...

Comment: @NitsanBaleli http://jsfiddle.net/21sv1bug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(row).find('input:hidden').val('')
```

use above after your function call

Comment: this worked after placing on the right place :)! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can empty the value of the input in the row with this jQuery code:

```
$(row).find('input').val('')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function cloneRow(tablename,rowname) {
    var value=$(this).prev('table').find('input:hidden').val(); // store the value in a variable
    $(this).prev('table').find('input:hidden').val(''); // empty the input
    var row = document.getElementById(rowname); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById(tablename); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    $(this).prev('table').find('input:hidden').val(value); // put the value in its place again
    $('.pickDate').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
    }); 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

A **[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/21sv1bug/2/)** using jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var clone=$(this).prev('table').find('tr:first').clone();
    clone.attr('id','newID');
    clone.find('input:hidden').val('');
    $(this).prev('table').append(clone);
});
```